Find a constant so that the limit at 1 exist
I thought this problem was going to be "easy" but I do not know what I am missing. The problem gives you this function $f(x) = 
     \begin{cases}
       \frac{\sin(\pi x)}{\ln{x}} &\quad\text{if}~x>1\\
       \frac{x^2+a}{x^2+x-2} &\quad\text{if}~x<1 ~\text{and}~x\neq -2 \\
     \end{cases}\\$
And ask you about the value of $a$ so that $f(x)$ has a limit at 1. First of all, $1$ is an accumulation point so taking the limit is nice. Now, I have 2 questions:

When it refers to the existence of the limit, does it have to be a real number.
Computing the limit as $x$ tends to 1 of $\frac{\sin(\pi x)}{\ln{x}}$ gives me $-\pi$. However, the limit of $\frac{x^2+a}{x^2+x-2}$ tends to $-\infty$ independent of the value of $a$, does this have sense?



In this context, yes. 2. Wrong: $a=-1$  gives another limit. Incidentally, don't write "the limit tends to $-\infty$". Either $f(x)$ tends to, or the limit equals.


There is a choice for $a$ such that both one sided limits exist,  but they aren't equal.

The general convention is to say a limit exists if it is finite, although some authors also include the possibility of $\pm\infty$. In this context, probably only finite limits are considered (it does not really affect the result).
As you already checked, the limit of $\dfrac{\sin(\pi x)}{\ln(x)}$ as $x\to 1$ is $-\pi$, so if the limit of $f$ exists, the only possibility is that it is equal to $-\pi$.
Now, if $a\neq -1$, we have $x^2+a\to 1+a\neq 0$ and $x^2+x-2\to 0$ when $x\to 1$. This implies $\dfrac{x^2+a}{x^2+x-2}$ has a vertical asymptote at $x=1$ if $a\neq -1$, implying that $f$ does not have a limit when $x\to 1$.
Now, if $a=1$, we have $$\dfrac{x^2+a}{x^2+x-2}=\dfrac{x^2-1}{x^2+x-2}=\dfrac{(x-1)(x+1)}{(x-1)(x+2)}$$
If $x\neq 1$ this function is the same as $\dfrac{x+1}{x+2}$, which clearly tends to $\dfrac{2}{3}\neq -\pi$ when $x\to 1$. This means that, again, $f$ does not have a limit when $x\to 1$.

@Julio_Puerta, again thanks for your time, with the comment of Anne Bauval I did exactly the reasoning you have shown.

Glad I could help.
